# Why am I getting a syntax error or server not defined error when running node server.js in command line for windows?

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line

I have tried opening my server.js file multiple times as well as a test file i named helloworld.js in cmd as well as gitbash and gitcmd.  Everytime I am returned with some sort of error whether it is a syntax:

[image]

or a cannot find module socket.io error

[image]

I have tried many things and ways including downloading gitbash and trying it there. I am fully new to any coding or dev and have read all of the other 20+ psots regarding the same thing but none of them seemed to have been resolved or documented?

Thank you

Comment: You're opening a Node command line first. That gives you a REPL which means takes whatever you type and runs it as JavaScript. Just type `node server.js`. Not `node<enter>node server.js`. That command will work in command prompt, git bash, mingw, etc.

Comment: Have you installed the socket.io module?

Comment: [Please do not post images of code or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714)

Answer (score -1):

In your first attempt:

`node server.js` is a command you are expected to run on your shell (bash, Windows Power Shell, etc). It launches Node.js and tells it to run the server.js module.

You are running `node` at the shell, which launches node and presents you with a REPL. You are then trying to run `node server.js` as if it were JavaScript (which it isn't, because it is shell).

Where you are currently typing `node`, instead type `node server.js`.

---

In your second attempt:

You are trying to load a module called socket.io, but it is not installed. You have to install it first.

Look at the [getting started guide](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/) for Socket.io.

It tells you how to set up a package manifest:

> First let’s create a package.json manifest file that describes our
>   project. I recommend you place it in a dedicated empty directory (I’ll
>   call mine chat-example).
>
> ```
> {
>   "name": "socket-chat-example",
>   "version": "0.0.1",
>   "description": "my first socket.io app",
>   "dependencies": {}
> }
> ```

and install modules while recording them as dependancies for your package:

> During development, socket.io serves the client automatically for us,
>   as we’ll see, so for now we only have to install one module:
>
> ```
> npm install --save socket.io
> ```

Answer (score -1):

If you have not already, go through the [Getting Started](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/) guide on the Socket.io website. From the guide:

- Make sure you have Node along with `npm` installed
- Perform an `npm init` to initialize your project
- perform an `npm install --save express`
- perform `npm install --save socket.io`
- When you want to run your Node app, do `node server.js`

Here is an example of what a correctly-formatted Socket.io server file should look like:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Make sure you have this in your client HTML file:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io();
</script>
```